# What is the benefit of an empty string value vs. using a null value

Tags: php, sql-server-2005, coding-style

Here is my problem:

Where I work, I need to run reports on a very large database. I'm using basic SQL queries in PHP to filter for exactly what I want. Every so often I'll get groups in my reports that do not meet the criteria of my search query.

I noticed that all of the "stragglers" that appear in my reports seemed to have NULL values in certain fields, consistently.

Looking at the database structure, I find that these NULL values in the database have a NOT NULL flag set on them.

It turns out that these are actually not NULL values and instead empty string values or $value = ''

In my past experience, when I was starting out I would make this mistake a lot, setting something = '' instead of making it NULL.

I've asked the DBA if he can think of any legitimate reason why these are set this way ( there are 300,000 some odd records that are like this ) and he had no clue.

I'm thinking it could be another programmers mistake or someone attempting to avoid not being able to insert the record due to the "NOT NULL" flag set on that specific field.

So I'm scratching my head over here trying to find a legitimate reason for these to exist, other than my own suspicions that the database was not designed for these 2 types of records: records with this value and records without this value.

What are your thoughts?

Comment: What's the default value on that field? If it's a default `''` empty string, then your "bad" records are due to inserts not specifying a value for it and the dbms simply giving it the default value instead.

Comment: It's most likely like this due to HTML forms containing empty strings. If I leave a field blank on a form, the code that processes the form probably doesn't simply not set that value, it sets it to the empty string value. I'm not exactly sure I fully understand what problem the empty string is causing you. Why would an empty string cause something to show up in a search?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of NULL as a value in database has its critics, I'd like to refer to the [Wikipedia article on NULL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_%28SQL%29#Common_mistakes) for an explanation of some of the oddities NULL may introduce in your queries.

So probably the database architect wasn't a fan of NULLs, maybe after reading "the Third Manifesto".  [This PDF](http://www.dcs.warwick.ac.uk/~hugh/TTM/Missing-info-without-nulls.pdf)  (by one of the authors of the Third Manifesto) can help you understand the problem and show you how to manage the special case of missing values can be handled.

Comment: Very informative FVU, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

> What is the benefit of an empty string value vs. using a null value

There are no real problems with using one or the other, exclusively. Issues arise when a single column can contain either, mainly with sorting and searching:

### Sorting

```
SELECT '' as c1
UNION 
SELECT NULL as c1
UNION
SELECT 'a' as c1
ORDER BY c1
```

You'll see that `NULL`s will be listed first, then string values (empty first). It's something to keep in mind if you're doing multi-column `ORDER BY`s and you're wondering why some columns are always on top.

### Searching

When a column is `NULL`, you need to search by `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL` rather than `= ''`. Also, when you do `LENGTH( c1 ) = 0`, these `NULL` records won't be included while empty strings will.

Finally, when you're comparing the column to itself in a self join, you won't be able to do a simple `=`.

---

All in all, it would be best to conform the column values to one or the other and make your SQL consistent.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen this pretty often, especially in cases where:

- The database is touched by a variety of clients (a primary application, ad-hoc queries, automated import interfaces...)
- Data has been converted or migrated from one system to another

There may not be a legitimate reason for it now, but it may have seemed like a good idea to someone else at the time. When you don't know the history of a database, it's hard to know the constraints or philosophies behind structural decisions.

I tend to be very careful around empty strings and nulls because I've been bitten by the same issues. There are often compatibility reasons that prevent changing the DB structure, so you're left with workarounds like using `ISNULL(c1,'')` or `COALESCE(c1,'')` to capture both nulls and empty strings.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the empty string represents the **absence of value**, while `NULL` represents an **unknown value**.

So, in my opinion, `""` is more specific, than `NULL`.  For example, if a person's birth place is not known, it is ok to store it as `NULL`, but not ok to store it as `""`.  If a person does not have any middle name, and it is known that the person does not have it, then it is better to store `""` than `NULL`.

Reason : `NULL` is the only way to indicate that a value is not known that works for all data types.  The empty string `""` is more like `0` for integers.